# Streaming from webcam: is it normal that the frame does not have refcount?

Tags: c++, opencv, webcam

I have the following code:

```
#include<opencv2/core/core.hpp>
#include<opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp>
int main()
{
    cv::VideoCapture capture(0);
    cv::Mat frame;
    capture>>frame;
    cv::Mat img = frame.clone();
    cv::Mat img2 = frame; // here still the refcount stays null in xcode.
    return 0;
}
```

then

```
frame.refcount ==NULL; // could be wrong
img->refcount == 1; // good
img2.refcount ==NULL; // certainly wrong, should be pointing to 2, at the same address as frame.refcount.
```

Everything seems to be working fine, but I have looked into things and it turned out that the refcount of the `frame` is just a null pointer (and stays so after `clone()`), whereas other mats (say its clone) have refcount pointing to an int >= 0.

What is the reason for this?

Comment: I would love to see a [Short, Self Contained, Correct (Compilable), Example](http://sscce.org/) that reproduces what you observed.

Comment: It turned out that I had a bug in my program at some other part too, but the question still remains, if you put it into an `int main(){}` and look at `frame` and `img` in the debugger, you'll see `frame::refcount=NULL` and it stays so after clone.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[According to the docs](http://opencv.willowgarage.com/documentation/cpp/basic_structures.html#mat):

> `clone()` returns deep copy of the matrix, i.e. the data is copied.

So **it makes sense that there's no increase in `refcount`**. For more information on this subject, take a look at [Memory management and reference counting](http://docs.opencv.org/2.4.3rc/doc/user_guide/ug_mat.html#memory-management-and-reference-counting).

Comment: Thanks for looking into this. Of course I know what clone should do, clarified the question from this aspect too.

Comment: I've done some tests and apparently, `refcount` only starts working after you clone() a Mat, or if you create a new Mat from one that was cloned. You might be on to something here :)